How to create data for a graph using calculations on another sheet
I have created a simple business analysis sheet in Google sheets, and it analyses how much profit there would be if x number of products were sold.
Now, I would like to create a graph starting with 0 products sold to, say, 100 products.
What is the best way to get all the profit value for each number of products sold?
The only way I can think of is to setup a new sheet and create a sequence of 0 to 100, and then use a script to setValue() in the number of products sold in the other sheet, and getValue() the profit from the same sheet.
But I am thinking there should be a better way, perhaps even without the script.


Yes, this would be possible with a couple of formulas. But more details/examples must be given in order to assist with this.

I am pasting here a screenshot of a simplified sheets, that calculates the profit.
Now, I would like to create a graph that automatically updates itself depending on the data I enter into this sheet.
The typical data I often play with are marked in red.
I would like to create a graph that shows from 0 customers to 100 customers, and it automatically updates itself if I change the value of the rent or the number of employees.

Formula For Multiplying Sequence
=byrow(SEQUENCE(100,1), LAMBDA(pft, MULTIPLY( pft, 30)))

You can try this. In this context the sequence is the number of products sold and the constant 30 is how much your profit per product sold. Feel free to change the constant based on your current situation or even the steps on the sequence to better project your analysis.
Sample Output:

References:
Byrow
Sequence

Feel Free to comment if you have questions about this formula and it's usage.

Thank you for the byrow() idea.
The actual calculation is done on a dfferent sheet, and it's much too complex to write it in a lambda function, and it also changes depending on the circumstances.
I pasted a simplified version of a screenshot, which calculates the net profit.
Now, I would like to create a graph with the number of customers on x axis from 0 to 100, and the net profit on y axis.
It should automatically update itself depending on the data I enter into this sheet. The typical data I often play with are the value of the rent and the number of employees.

It seems that your additional question falls into different segment of your project. I suggest creating another post about it instead. About using the Lambda function on the profit, you can simply change the 30 on the formula I have provided to a reference cell. It should work the same. Creation of graph you want might fall on creating a script so it can automatically create data points depending on the values.
